# update database, how to check it wrote the data

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I am using Python to write on a mongoDB database a very large amount of data. Some of this data can actually overwrite old data already in the database. I am using pymongo and MongoClient using update function.

Since i am writing ten of thousands of datapoints in the database, can i make sure that the data is actually being written properly, how can i check if any data has not been written on mongoDB? I dont want to add to much code to that as it it already quite slow to download and write everything. If there is no easy answer, i will sacrifice speed but i want to make sure everything goes into mongoDB.

Comment: Can you show your db structure and query, that you are trying to update?

Answer (score 2):

When you execute an insert_one or insert_many instruction, you should get a result value. You can check this to make sure that the insert was successful.

```
result = posts.insert_many(new_posts)
print result.inserted_id
```